# How to receive JSON data with Python (server with websockets) and JavaScript (client-side)

Tags: javascript, python, json, websocket

I have a newbie question with receiving JSON data from Python working as a server. I need to tell you that the server is based on WebSockets and I'm sending JSON data from Python to JavaScript successfully but I can't find any source how to proceed with this data to parse this and show it in different divs like value of the `first_name` in the `id="message-1"` `div`, `second_name` in the `message2` `div` etc. Could you help me figure this out? Here is the code and picture what my firefox return: [Web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQl9R.png).

I almost forgot to mention that I'm using localhost with xampp or [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to "host" my client-side. Also, there is a connection because I'm receiving logs on the website as well as in python console

Thanks in advance :)

Here is python code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json


async def time(websocket, path):
    while True:
        d = {'first_name': 'Guido',
             'second_name': 'Rossum',
             'titles': ['BDFL', 'Developer'],
             }
        parsed = json.dumps(d)
        name = "Jeremy"
        # now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
        for i in range(1):
            await websocket.send(parsed)
            response = await websocket.recv()
            print(response)
        start_server = websockets.serve(time, '127.0.0.1', 4040)


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Here is HTML/JS code

```
<body>
<div id="message-1"></div>
<div id="message-2"></div>
<div id="message-3"></div>
<script>
    var ws       = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:4040/");
    ws.onopen    = function () {
        ws.send('Hello, Server!!');
        //send a message to server once ws is opened.
        console.log("It's working onopen log / awake");
    };
    ws.onmessage = function (event) {
        if (typeof event.data === "string") {
            // If the server has sent text data, then display it.
            console.log("On message is working on log with onmessage :)");
            var label       = document.getElementById("message-1");
            label.innerHTML = event.data;
        }
    };
    ws.onerror   = function (error) {
        console.log('Error Logged: ' + error); //log errors
    };
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: where does object comes?  Is it `event.data` ? `event.data` is always string right?

Comment: I have added a possible solution, let me know if it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### You need to parse the message you received and attach it to the dom!

```
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    try {
        var obj  = JSON.parse(event.data);
        document.getElementById("message-1").innerHTML = obj.first_name;
        document.getElementById("message-2").innerHTML = obj.second_name;
        document.getElementById("message-3").innerHTML = obj.titles.join(" ");
    } catch {
        console.log("Object is not received, Message is:: ", event.data);
    }
}
```

#### If this is not working, then check the json format your are sending!

> Remember JSON Needs to be valid json, Replace `'` (single-quote) with `"` (double-quote):

```
d = {
    "first_name": "Guido",
    "second_name": "Rossum",
    "titles": ["BDFL", "Developer"]
}
```