# How can I send json to client in websockets using js and print the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

I want to parse a json like this from the server

```
{"prevCount":0, "addition":5, "type":"small"}
```

there are more values
I tried this way but it doesn't work
I want to calculate this in realtime, so as soon as they change values in server should update the client as well

**here's my server**

```
server.on('connection', function(ws) {
console.log('connected');
ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
    console.log('received: ' + util.inspect(data));
    //ws.send(data, { binary: flags.binary });
ws.send(JSON.stringify({"prevCount":0, "addition":5, "type":"small"}))

});

ws.on('close', function() {
    console.log('close');
});
```

});

**client onmessage**

```
// Handle incoming websocket message callback
    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
        log("Message Received: " + evt.data)
        //alert("message received: " + evt.data);
        var obj = JSON.parse(evt.data);
        var type = obj.type;
        var prevCount = obj.prevCount;
        var addition = obj.addition;

        if(obj.type==small){
            $('td#sCount').text(obj.prevCount + obj.addition)
        }
        if(obj.type==medium){
            $('td#mCount').text(obj.prevCount + obj.addition)
        }
        if(obj.type==large){
            $('td#lCount').text(obj.prevCount + obj.addition)
        }
        if(obj.type==twol){
            $('td#2lCount').text(obj.prevCount + obj.addition)
        }
    };
```

**my html code**

```
                <td style="width: 164px; height: 55px;">Small</td>
                <td style="width: 273px; height: 55px;" id="sCount">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 55px;">
                <td style="width: 164px; height: 55px;">Medium</td>
                <td style="width: 273px; height: 55px;" id="mCount">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="height: 55px;">
                <td style="width: 164px; height: 55px;">Large</td>
                <td style="width: 273px; height: 55px;" id="lCount">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
```

**the output should be like this:**

- small - total
- medium - total
- large - total

Howver my code doesn't work
nothing prints in table columns

Any help is appreciated

**Note**-client is in jquery

I found this one
[How to receive JSON data with Python (server with websockets) and JavaScript (client-side)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51323651/how-to-receive-json-data-with-python-server-with-websockets-and-javascript-cl)

I took an idea from this but its server is on python mine is js, didn't work

Comment: BTW are you able to receive the message you are sending from server ?  if yes then you are able to parse the data correctly  ?... if yes again then check you are selecting the right HTML element to be updated. 
Also make sure that you have proper HTML for table.

Comment: no i don't receive the data. So i believe the way i connected the json is wrong in server

Comment: since i don't know the exact tools / library which you are using on server and client end also don't have full code, I can't say much ... if you are using socket.io then you will find this link useful

https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/2504541-ultra-fast-applications-using-node-js/2505653-socket-io-let-s-go-to-real-time